# Swift: rotate imageView around left side

Tags: ios, swift

I have this code to rotate `imageView` around its axis (center of image):

```
transform.m34 = 1.0 / -2000.0
self.imageRevealed1.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(CGFloat(Double.pi), 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
```

But I need rotate `imageView` around its left side. How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should modify the view [anchorPoint](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410817-anchorpoint) before set the layer transform. Example, in your case, the anchorPoint should set `CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5)`, then set transform.